# SQL - Count per month/year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains 2 timestamps, one is for arrival of an object on site and the second one is when that objects leaves the site.

I would like a query that will show me how many objects were on site per month/year, even if it was only for one day it should add up to that month.

My sample data looks like this:

```
Object    || ArrivalDate || LeaveDate  
Object 1  || 01-JAN-2016 || 28-JAN-2016  
Object 2  || 01-JAN-2016 || 31-MAR-2016  
Object 3  || 01-JAN-2016 || 25-FEB-2016  
Object 1  || 1-FEB-2016  || 28-MAR-2016  
Object 4  || 5-FEB-2016  || 1-APR-2016
```

I would like a query that would show that the following results:
JAN-2016 3
FEB-2016 4
MAR-2016 3
APR-2016 1

How would I do this, I can't get my head around it.

Comment: specify your sample data and desired result

Comment: Also, "how many objects where on site per month/year" is vague.  Do you want to know how many were on site at any point during that month, at the start, at the end, at some arbitrary day in the middle?

Comment: Question changed to be more explanatory

Answer (score 1):

On a basic level:

```
select 'Jan' as Period, count(Items) as Items
from MyTable
where (LeaveDate > '2016-01-01' or LeaveDate is null)
and EnterDate < '2016-02-01'
```

I would recommend using a calendar table though, but this is a basic concept.

Answer (score 0):

- A is the count of objets that arrived the year,
- B is the count of objets that left this the year,
- C is the count of objects that arrived and left the year
- D is the object that arrived before the year, and left after

The number of objects that were on your website is D+A+B-C

In tsql :

```
SELECT ((SELECT count(*)
     FROM mytable 
     WHERE (leaveDate >= '01-01-2016' 
            AND leaveDate <= '12-31-2016')) +
    (SELECT count(*)
     FROM mytable
     WHERE enterDate <= 01-01-2016 
           AND leaveDate >= 12-31-2016) + 
    (SELECT count(*)
     FROM mytable
     WHERE enterDate >= 01-01-2016
           AND enterDate <= 12-31-2016) -
    (SELECT count(*)
    FROM mytable
    WHERE enterDate >= 01-01-2016
          AND enterDate <= 12-31-2016
          AND leaveDate >= 01-01-2016
          AND leaveDate <= 12-31-2016)) AS total;
```

If I didn't do a mistake that'll give you all the objects on your website in 2016

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with cumulative sums.  The idea is to count the number of enters and leaves each month, and then do a cumulative sum over the values:

```
select yyyy, mm, sum(cnt),
       sum(sum(cnt)) over (order by yyyy, mm)
from ((select year(enterdate) as yyyy, month(enterdate) as mm, count(*) as cnt
       from t 
       group by year(enterdate) as yyyy, month(enterdate)
      ) union all
      (select year(leavedate) as yyyy, month(leavedate) as mm, - count(*) as cnt
       from t 
       group by year(leavedate) as yyyy, month(leavedate)
      )
     ) t
group by yyyy, mm
order by yyyy, mm;
```